# I have error after using aggregate mongoose mongoDb in my Api

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

"error": {
"ok": 0,
"code": 5107201,
"codeName": "Location5107201",
"$clusterTime": {
"clusterTime": {
"$timestamp": "7292060947630260235"
},
"signature": {
"hash": "HQW2T+0z31Kf8q6iLViqdu0uYtQ=",
"keyId": {
"low": 2,
"high": 1683641553,
"unsigned": false
}
}
},
"operationTime": {
"$timestamp": "7292060947630260235"
}
}

```js
let page = 1;
let limit = 10;
let sort = {};
let skip =(page-1)*limit
//req.query.sort is coming as 'name' or '-name'
  if (req.query.sort) {
     const key = req.query.sort;
     if (req.query.sort[0] === "-") {
        sort[`${key.substring(1)}`] = -1;
        sort["_id"] = 1;
     } else {
        sort[`${key}`] = 1;
        sort["_id"] = 1;
     }
  } else {
     sort.dateCreated = 1;
  }

const reviewsList = await Review.aggregate([
     { $match: filter },
     {
        $lookup: {
           from: "users",
           localField: "user",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "user",
        },
     },
     {
        $unwind: "$user",
     },
     {
        $lookup: {
           from: "products",
           localField: "product",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "product",
        },
     },
     {
        $unwind: "$product",
     },
     {
        $sort: sort,
     },
     { $skip: skip },
     { $limit: limit },
  ]);
```

Comment: Searching the `codeName` from your error message surfaces [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71768412/mongodb-5-0-query-returing-location517200-error-code). Are you passing a bad value to `$skip`?

Comment: yes, I saw this question and change $skip several times but coudn't solve the problem

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the page and limit were String

> ```
> const reviewsList = await Review.aggregate([
>           .......
>          { $skip: +skip },
>          { $limit: +limit },
>       ]);
> ```